# laravel 5 registration form

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to make a registration form in laravel 5 and it gives me this error:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1
>     TokenMismatchException in compiled.php line 2440:

This is my views/register.blade.php:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action = "inregistrare_process" method = "POST">
.....
</form>
```

This is in my app/Register.php

```
    <?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Register extends Eloquent {
        protected $guarded = array();
        protected $table = 'users'; 
        public $timestamps = 'false' ; 


        public static function saveFormData($data)
        {
            DB::table('users')->insert($data);
        }

}
```

This is my Controllers/RegisterController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Register;
class RegisterController extends Controller {



public function store()
{
    Register::saveFormData(Input::except(array('_token')));
}

}
```

And this is in my routes.php

```
Route::get('inregistrare',function(){

    return view('register');
});

Route::post('inregistrare_process', function()
{
        $obj = new RegisterController() ;
        return $obj->store();
});
```

Can someone help me make this work or give me another alternative on how to make the registration page work ?

Comment: Did you include a hidden field in your submission form with a value of {{ crsf_token() }}   - like this: <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all you need a hidden input type with csrf_token in form

insert below line after your form declaration

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

2. Do you have write permission for your session file. By default session is stored in /storage/framework/sessions/
   check that you have write permission on that directory.
3. If you are using an Ajax request than add the tokenMatch() method to app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php.

   ```
   protected function tokensMatch($request)
   {
       $token = $request->ajax() ? $request->header('X-CSRF-Token') : $request->input('_token');

       return $request->session()->token() == $token;
   }
   ```

and add this in your js file

```
$.ajaxSetup(
{
    headers:
    {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
    }
});
```

Comment: it works ,that error has gone but insted i get a new one:FatalErrorException in routes.php line 32:
Class 'RegisterController' not found. Can you tell me how can i handle this too please ?

Comment: laravel didn't find 'RegisterController' class in your app, Is there any 'RegisterController' class ?? Did you defined any RegisterController class?

Comment: well in my Controllers/RegisterController.php i did

Comment: rather than using a function use this Route::post('inregistrare_process', 'RegisterController@store' );

Comment: Input class not found,is there any Input class in controller folder??

Comment: yeah i just had to write use Input; on the top of the page.